# How to make an HTML countdown timer that resets on reload?

Tags: javascript, html, timer, countdown

How would I go about making a countdown clock using only HTML and JS? Problem is, there are a few features that are required:
• It must reset on a page reload
• It must count down from a certain number of hours **from page load** (i.e. not a universal time)

I realize these are a lot of demands, but anything hints/tips/advice will help. Thanks in advance :]

I've tried some online timers, but they are universal and don't reset on a page reload.

Comment: I tried this timer reset on page reload https://www.timeanddate.com/timer/, maybe you meant something else right?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Please, learn how to write good question (which, also includes posting minimum reproducible). [How do I ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you've tried. Here's one.

(Although, to be honest, I probably shouldn't answer a poorly written question.)

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
<script> {
    let remaining = { hours: 1, minutes: 0, seconds: 5 }
    
    displayRemainingTime();

    const countdownInterval = 
    setInterval( () => {

        --remaining.seconds;

        if( remaining.seconds < 0 ) {

            --remaining.minutes;

            if( remaining.minutes < 0 ) {

                --remaining.hours;

                if( remaining.hours < 0 ) {

                    clearInterval( countdownInterval );
                    displayRemainingTime();

                } else {

                    remaining.minutes = 59;
                    remaining.seconds = 59;

                }


            } else {

                remaining.seconds = 59;

            }

        }

        displayRemainingTime();

    }, 1000 );

    function displayTimerFinished() {

        document.getElementById( "countdown" ).textContent = "The timer has finished!";

    }

    function displayRemainingTime() {

        const hoursDigit = remaining.hours < 10 ? "0" : "",
            minutesDigit = remaining.minutes < 10 ? "0" : "",
            secondsDigit = remaining.seconds < 10 ? "0" : "";

        document.getElementById( "countdown" ).textContent =
            `${hoursDigit + remaining.hours}:${minutesDigit + remaining.minutes}:${secondsDigit + remaining.seconds}`;

    }

} </script>
```